# Where are the field labels and descriptions stored?

Tags: entities

I have been exploring Drupal 8 and it's tables lately. The config table has the storage information serialized as blob. But it doesn't store the Label or Description of a field. Where can one find these data? Is there a core function which helps in fetching all these data for a particular content type?

Comment: As basically everything is an entity (content + configuration) core's [entity api](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/introduction-to-entity-api-in-drupal-8) offers everything you need to fetch the data you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :-

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node) {
$field_label = $node->field_file->getFieldDefinition()->getLabel();
$field_desc = $node->field_file->getFieldDefinition()->getDescription();
$field_settings = $node->field_file->getFieldDefinition()->getSettings();
}
```